# django contains any query

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to make a query that selects all uuids of ProblemSet whose problems contains at least one problem with a specific problem type. How can I do it in Django? In mysql it will be a simple join but django's '__contains' doesn't serve the needs..

Thanks!!

```
class ProblemType:
  name ..... (many fields)

class Problem:
  problem_type = models.ManyToManyField(ProblemType)
  ...... (many fields)

class ProblemSet:
  problems = models.ManyToMnayField(Problem)
  uuid = models.CharField(...)
  ...... (many fields)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does a normal `filter` not work?

```
uuids = ProblemSet.objects.filter(problems__problem_type__name='MyProblemType')
    .values_list('uuid', flat=True)
```

Also, do your problems have multiple `problem_type`s? If so, then you should reflect that fact by renaming your `ManyToManyField` as `problem_types` (note the pluralization). Otherwise, you shouldn't use a `ManyToManyField`.